# C# mouse click event after focus in windows 2012

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, focus, mouseclick-event

I find a strange bug in windows 2012. I have a simple window (WinForm) with a text box and a button (textBox1 and button1).And I try to focus on textbox1, after form appear.

```
private void Find_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Focus();           
}
```

And if I set it `Click` and `MouseClick` events stop working. So I can't click on button.
In windows 2008 it's work. If comment focus line - works too.

Who can suggest a solution or perhaps an alternative? Need to get the cursor in the  textbox after the form has appeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Shown` event instead:

```
private void Find_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e){
  textBox1.Focus();
}
```

**Note**: you used `Paint` event which will be very nasty, everytime your form is repainted, your `textBox1` will be focused, the `Paint` event is fired every time your form resizes, state changes, ... we can't determine exactly the time it fires but it fires fairly frequently when your form is running. That is the reason why you can't click on and select anything on your form. That's because clicking or selecting controls fires the `Paint` event and makes your `textBox1` focused then.

Comment: It's a bit strange, because original application to run in windows environment in 2008 and works as expected. And yes, Shown event is actually better. Thank you.